# Calculate start date and end date when Fiscal year and Quarter numbers are given

Tags: sql, sql-server

what is the formula for start day of the quarter when year and quarter as given as parameters with datatype INT

```
Declare @Year INT = 2019
Declare @Quarter TINYINT = 1
```

Result expected :

```
07/01/2019 as start date 
10/31/2019 as end date
```

Query gives me the last day of the quarter , but looking for last day of fiscal year quarter

```
Select dateadd(day, -1, 
                       dateadd(year, @year-1900,
                                          dateadd(quarter, @Quarter, 0)
                                     )
             )
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  How do you get 2019-07-01 for the start of the first quarter?

Comment: That is what I am looking for , how to achieve the FY start date and end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(year, quarter * 3 - 2, 1) soq,
       dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 3, datefromparts(year, quarter * 3 - 2, 1))) as eoq
```

If your fiscal year starts on July 1st, then you can add six months:

```
select dateadd(month, 6, datefromparts(year, quarter * 3 - 2, 1)) soq,
       dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 9, datefromparts(year, quarter * 3 - 2, 1))) as eoq
```

Comment: If the fiscal year starts at 07/01/2019 , how do we get that ?

Comment: @Swara . . . The answer addresses that.